# how to print array values in different textbox

Tags: php, mysqli

I have these values inside a table [image: here]

and I want them to print in each of the textboxes like

[image: this]

Can anyone help me with that?

This is my code so far

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $spnsrArr = $conn->query("SELECT bap_sponsors.* FROM bap_sponsors WHERE bap_id='$bapID'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($spnsrArr);
         $spnsrName = $row['sponsors_name'];
         $spnsrAge = $row['sponsors_age'];
         $spnsrReligion = $row['sponsors_religion'];
         $spnsrPlace = $row['sponsors_residence'];

 ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<label>SPONSOR #1</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h5>Name:</h5>
    <input type="text" name="$spnsName[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrName; ?>" disabled="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <h5>Age:</h5>
    <input type="number" name="age[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrAge; ?>" disabled="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h5>Religion:</h5>
    <input type="text" name="spnsrreligion[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrReligion; ?>" disabled="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h5>Residence:</h5>
    <input type="text" name="spnsrresidence[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrPlace; ?>" disabled="" /><br>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put all info in the question, no external links please, I wont click on these (nana nana nana nana phishing!).  What do you see you do not like? What is the error?

Comment: @Nic what do you mean "phishing"? Those are imgur links, there's no phishing here.

Comment: Iterate over results with a `foreach`

Comment: Thanks for adding the content in the question.  It avoids the question being useless if the imgur links die off later.  I was not implying you were trying to phish us, just that some others could, and most will avoid cliking external links.  Now please add what you see with your code, do you have errors, ...?

Comment: sorry about the image links. I'm still new to stakoverflow so i don't know the other way to show them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query

```
$spnsrArr = $conn->query("SELECT bap_sponsors.* FROM bap_sponsors WHERE bap_id='$bapID'");
```

returns several rows. But

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($spnsrArr);
```

fetches only **one**.

You should iterate over results, calling `mysqli_fetch_array` several times. This is usually done with `while`:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($spnsrArr)) {
    $spnsrName = $row['sponsors_name'];
    $spnsrAge = $row['sponsors_age'];
    $spnsrReligion = $row['sponsors_religion'];
    $spnsrPlace = $row['sponsors_residence'];
    $i++;
    ?>
    <label>SPONSOR #<?php echo $i;?></label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5>Name:</h5>
        <input type="text" name="spnsName[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrName; ?>" disabled="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h5>Age:</h5>
        <input type="number" name="age[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrAge; ?>" disabled="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>Religion:</h5>
        <input type="text" name="spnsrreligion[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrReligion; ?>" disabled="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>Residence:</h5>
        <input type="text" name="spnsrresidence[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spnsrPlace; ?>" disabled="" /><br>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Also note I removed `$` in `name="$spnsName[]"`.